# electron and lowdb not work

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a problem with the following code. I used electron and lowdb for json file.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("./tmp/data.json", function(data) {
                var employee_data = '';

                $.each(data.prodotti, function(key, value){
                      //var ver = db.get('porodotti').value('id')
                        var  id = '<td id = "cella">'+value.id+'</td>';
                        employee_data += '<tr>';
                        employee_data += '<td>'+value.articolo +' - '+ value.descrizione+'</td>';
                        employee_data += '<td>'+'€'+''+value.prezzo +',00'+'</td>';
                        employee_data += '<td>'+value.quantita+'</td>';
                        employee_data += '<td>'+'€'+''+value.totale +',00'+'</td>';
                        employee_data += '<td><a href="#" class="ico-del"></a></td>';
                        employee_data += '</tr>';

                        });
                $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);
        });
        $("#employee_table").on('click', '.ico-del', function () {
             db.get('prodotti').remove({ articolo: value.articolo}).write()
             $(this).closest('tr').remove();
             alert("Articolo rimosso correttamente");
    });
});
```

when I go to delete the row in the table,this is deleted from the table, but it gives me the error in the deletion of the corresponding values ​​in the json file.

I would be very grateful to those who help me solve this problem.

thank you